# Sequence of functions inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I need some help to prove that $f_n(x)\leq 1$ , where $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R},  f_n(x)=\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}, n\in\mathbb{N}$. 
 I can write $(1+x^2)^n=\binom{0}{n}x^n+\binom{1}{n}x^{n-1}y+\binom{2}{n}x^{n-2}y^2+...+\binom{n-2}{n}x^2y^{n-2}+\binom{n-1}{n}xy^{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}y^n=\\x^n+nx^{n-1}y+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^{n-2}y^2+...+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2y^{n-2}+nxy^{n-1}+y^n$
$\\$
I unsuccessfully tried to find $1+nx^2$ in $(1+x^2)^n$ to show that $1+nx^2\leq(1+x^2)^n$.

Comment: You did not substitute $1$ and $x^2$ for $x$ and  $y$ in the binomial expansion. If you do that then you'll get  $(1+x^2)^n = 1 + n x^2 + \ldots \ge 1 + n x^2$.

Comment: It is also an immediate result of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not substitute $1$ and $x^2$ for $x$ and $y$ in the binomial theorem. The correct expansion is
$$
 (1+x^2)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk 1^{n-k}(x^2)^k = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^{2k} \, .
$$
It follows (by taking only the first two terms of the sum) that
$$
 (1+x^2)^n 
\ge  \binom n0 x^0 + \binom n1 x^2 = 1 + n x^2 \, .
$$

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate the function $\frac{1+nx²}{(1+x²)^{n})}$ which comes out to be $\frac{2n(1-n)x^3(1+x²)^{n-1}}{(1+x²)^{2n}}$. Which obviously = 0 if n=1 and <0 if x >0 , n>1.We can conclude for any n maximum value of function in (0,1) occurs at 0 . At zero function is 1for any n. So maximum value of function is 1 for any value of n.

Answer (score 1):

$1+nx^2\le(1+x^2)^n$ is true by Bernoulli's inequality, since $x^2\ge0$. Thus $f_n(x)\le1$.